# yum remove package freeze while erasing

Tags: centos6, yum

I'm using CentOS 6.5 on a server.
Some time ago, I installed from a third-party repository Newscoop CMS.
Now I'm not able to remove it.

```
yum remove newscoop
```

Freeze at the "erasing" point, shutting down apache.
This is the entire output of the operation until it stuck.

```
sudo yum remove newscoop.noarch
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Config time: 0.193
Running "init" handler for "fastestmirror" plugin
Yum Version: 3.2.29
COMMAND: yum remove newscoop.noarch
Installroot: /
Ext Commands:

   newscoop.noarch
Reading Local RPMDB
rpmdb time: 0.001
Setting up Remove Process
Resolving Dependencies
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to
finish them.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package newscoop.noarch 0:4.2.3-1 will be erased
Checking deps for newscoop.noarch 0:4.2.3-1 - e
---> Package newscoop.noarch 0:4.2.4-1 will be erased
Checking deps for newscoop.noarch 0:4.2.4-1 - e
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Dependency Process ending
base                                                                                         | 3.7 kB     00:00    
epel/metalink                                                                                |  28 kB     00:00    
epel                                                                                         | 4.4 kB     00:00    
epel/primary_db                                                                              | 5.2 MB     00:00    
extras                                                                                       | 3.3 kB     00:00    
kbs-CentOS-Extras                                                                            | 1.9 kB     00:00    
kbs-CentOS-Testing                                                                           | 1.9 kB     00:00    
rpmforge                                                                                     | 1.9 kB     00:00    
sourcefabric                                                                                 |  951 B     00:00    
sourcefabric-source                                                                          |  951 B     00:00    
updates                                                                                      | 3.4 kB     00:00    
updates/primary_db                                                                           | 5.0 MB     00:00    
Depsolve time: 16.051

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================================================
 Package                    Arch                    Version                 Repository                    Size
================================================================================================================
Removing:
 newscoop                   noarch                  4.2.3-1                 installed                     111 M
 newscoop                   noarch                  4.2.4-1                 installed                     110 M

Transaction Summary
=================================================================================================================
Remove        2 Package(s)

Installed size: 221 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Member: newscoop.noarch 0:4.2.3-1 - e
Removing Package newscoop-4.2.3-1.noarch
Member: newscoop.noarch 0:4.2.4-1 - e
Removing Package newscoop-4.2.4-1.noarch
rpm_check_debug time: 1.078
Running Transaction Test
Member: newscoop.noarch 0:4.2.3-1 - e
Removing Package newscoop-4.2.3-1.noarch
Member: newscoop.noarch 0:4.2.4-1 - e
Removing Package newscoop-4.2.4-1.noarch
Transaction Test Succeeded
Transaction Test time: 22.134
Member: newscoop.noarch 0:4.2.3-1 - e
Removing Package newscoop-4.2.3-1.noarch
Member: newscoop.noarch 0:4.2.4-1 - e
Removing Package newscoop-4.2.4-1.noarch
Running Transaction
  Erasing    : newscoop.noarch                                                                              1/2
```

`yum-complete-transaction` doesn't solve the problem.

Actually, I'm not able to remove this package.

Comment: What is the exact error message and related text you are being provided by the command ?

Comment: Actually, there is not an error. It's just stuck at the "erasing..." stage. I left the process active for 3 hours and it was still there.

Comment: It's still not clear exactly what's (not) happening can you show us the text you have been provided by the command please.

Comment: I added the entire output of `sudo yum remove newscoop` as requested. Thank you @Iain for the replies.

Comment: Ugh.  That moment when you have the EXACT same issue and don't see an answer. @Kropot, how did you proceed?